# Spring data R2DBC: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, querydsl, spring-data-r2dbc

I am trying to use **ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor** along with R2dbcRepository for my spring-data-r2dbc application with r2dbc-mssql client version 0.8.1.RELEASE

I upgraded the **spring-boot** version from 2.2.7.RELEASE to **2.3.0.RELEASE** and **spring-data-r2dbc** version from 1.0.0.RELEASE to **1.1.0.RELEASE**. I am using query-dsl version 4.3.1 to generate the Q-Classes with apt-maven-plugin.

After making these changes, when I run my application, I get the following error. I have been trying all day but couldn't find anything to make it work. Is there anything I am missing?

**NOTE:** The application runs perfectly fine if I don't make the above changes and don't extend the ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor in my repository class.

**Model Class**

```
@Table(value = "db_access_schema.access_control")
@QueryEntity
public class AccessControl implements Persistable<UUID> {

  @Id
  private UUID id;
  private Long iub;
  private Long iubHeadOffice;
  private String bncId;
  private String subjectId;
  private String subjectTypeCd;
  private String subjectIdTypeCd;
  private String objectId;
  private String objectTypeCd;
  private String objectIdTypeCd;
  private String actionCd;
  private String comments;
  private Boolean isActive;

  @Override
  public boolean isNew() {
    boolean result = Objects.isNull(id);
    this.id = result ? UUID.randomUUID() : this.id;
    return result;
  }

   // getters and setters

}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface AccessControlRepository extends R2dbcRepository<AccessControl, UUID> ,
        ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor<AccessControl> {

  String SCHEMA = "db_access_schema.";

  @Query("select * from " + SCHEMA + "access_control where id = :id")
  Mono<AccessControl> findById(@Param("id") UUID id);

  @Query("select * from " + SCHEMA + "access_control where object_id = :objectId and iub = :iub")
  Mono<AccessControl> findByObjectIdAndIub(@Param("objectId") String objectId, @Param("iub") Long iub);

  @Query("select * from " + SCHEMA + "access_control where iub IN (:iubs)")
  Flux<AccessControl> findByIubIn(@Param("iubs") List<Long> iubs);

  /*  @Query("select * from " + SCHEMA + "access_control")
  Flux<AccessControl> findAll();*/

  @Query("select * from " + SCHEMA + "access_control where is_active = :isActive")
  Flux<AccessControl> findByIsActive(@Param("isActive") Boolean isActive);
}
```

**STACK TRACE:**

```
ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessControlHandler' defined in file [/Users/josa003/Projects/BNE/access-control-pip/target/classes/ca/bnc/bne/accesscontrol/handler/AccessControlHandler.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessControlService' defined in file [/Users/josa003/Projects/BNE/access-control-pip/target/classes/ca/bnc/bne/accesscontrol/service/AccessControlService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessControlRepository' defined in ca.bnc.bne.accesscontrol.repository.AccessControlRepository defined in @EnableR2dbcRepositories declared on DatabaseConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract reactor.core.publisher.Flux org.springframework.data.querydsl.ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor.findAll(com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate,com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier[])! No property findAll found for type AccessControl!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at ca.bnc.bne.accesscontrol.TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessControlService' defined in file [/Users/josa003/Projects/BNE/access-control-pip/target/classes/ca/bnc/bne/accesscontrol/service/AccessControlService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessControlRepository' defined in ca.bnc.bne.accesscontrol.repository.AccessControlRepository defined in @EnableR2dbcRepositories declared on DatabaseConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract reactor.core.publisher.Flux org.springframework.data.querydsl.ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor.findAll(com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate,com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier[])! No property findAll found for type AccessControl!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessControlRepository' defined in ca.bnc.bne.accesscontrol.repository.AccessControlRepository defined in @EnableR2dbcRepositories declared on DatabaseConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract reactor.core.publisher.Flux org.springframework.data.querydsl.ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor.findAll(com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate,com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier[])! No property findAll found for type AccessControl!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract reactor.core.publisher.Flux org.springframework.data.querydsl.ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor.findAll(com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate,com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier[])! No property findAll found for type AccessControl!
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.query.PartTreeR2dbcQuery.<init>(PartTreeR2dbcQuery.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.support.R2dbcRepositoryFactory$R2dbcQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(R2dbcRepositoryFactory.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:92)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1054)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:331)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.support.R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type AccessControl!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:251)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:252)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:381)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:382)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.query.PartTreeR2dbcQuery.<init>(PartTreeR2dbcQuery.java:66)
    ... 67 common frames omitted
2875  WARN  o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Unable to close ApplicationContext
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityAutoConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.ReactiveMethodSecurityConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:134)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.availability.AvailabilityChangeEvent.publish(AvailabilityChangeEvent.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.availability.AvailabilityChangeEvent.publish(AvailabilityChangeEvent.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:978)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:814)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at ca.bnc.bne.accesscontrol.TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.ReactiveMethodSecurityConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:814)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Same here for me albeit with Spring Data Mongo and Spring Boot 2.3.0.

Comment: Same problem when upgrade spring boot to version 2.3.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Please add the whole stacktrace, especially the part before the first "caused by" section.

Comment: @mle updated the post with whole stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

This exception isn't the actual cause of your problem.
Check your startup logs above to find the real error, for example:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'management.metrics.distribution.slo' to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.ServiceLevelObjectiveBoundary[]>:
```

Comment: Very good point. Spring errors are not always easy to trace. And this is a key point to have always in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your detailed stacktrace. Now the underlying issue gets clearer.

Take a close look at this line:
`Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type AccessControl!`

The most probable cause is an invalid named method in your Spring repository. Keep in mind that valid properties are only those which are mentioned in your domain model, in this case `AccessControl`.

With respect to Querydsl, this seems not to be supported by R2DBC as stated by Mark Paluch in this [issue comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/353#issuecomment-617614411).

Comment: Hello @mle, even though I removed findAll from the repository, the error still remains. I even replaced findAll with findByIsActive, which is a valid property of AccessControl but to no avail.

Comment: Could you please show model and repo? Please give also `findByActive` a try.

Comment: updated the post with Model and Repository class. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks and now also the updated error stacktrace please. The former still complains about findAll.

Comment: Try also to omit the `@Query` and `@Param` annotations. I can't see why they should be necessary in your current code.

Comment: The error stack is still the same. Also the @Query annotation is needed as the underlying r2dbc-mssql client does not support query derivation yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214424/discussion-between-ankit-and-mle).

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported by spring data r2dbc yet - see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/529.

If you don't mind using another library to step in you can try out https://github.com/infobip/infobip-spring-data-querydsl#R2DBC. It provides support for `ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor` fragment and `QuerydslR2dbcFragment`.